# What is the DATATYPE for QUERY_TIME Column in MySQL slow query log Table?

Tags: mysql

While Logging slow-query into the mysql slow-log table,if the query time is less the 1 second ie (microseconds),query-time column is inserting as 00:00:00.In slow query log file its fine as 0.75555 seconds.

**I am using mysql 5.1.33**

so I need Datatype for Query time Column to insert microseconds also.

Comment: [FLOAT, DOUBLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html)?

Comment: Thanks for Leri But I am being inserting slow-log-query to table insted of file.The mysql inserts into the Query-time column as 00:00:12,In file it is inserting as 0.120000 seconds.                       If I do datatype as float or double it is inserting 0.

Comment: You need to define decimal points count. For example, `FLOAT(9,4)`.

Comment: It is inserting as 0.0000 I think microseconds is suporting after mysql 5.6.1